# Configuring end to end SSL using Nginx Ingress controller

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am running a local deployment and trying to redirect HTTPS traffic to my backend pods.
I don't want SSL termination at the Ingress level, which is why I didn't use any tls secrets.

I am creating a self signed cert within the container, and Tomcat starts up by picking that and exposing on 8443.

Here is my Ingress Spec

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-name
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/service-upstream: "false"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: {{ .Values.global.ingressClass }}
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
        - path: /myserver
          backend:
            serviceName: myserver
            servicePort: 8443
```

I used the above annotation in different combinations but I still can't reach my pod.

My service routes

```
# service information for myserver
service:
  type: ClusterIP
  port: 8443
  targetPort: 8443
  protocol: TCP
```

I did see a few answers regarding this suggesting annotations, but that didn't seem to work for me. Thanks in advance!

edit: The only thing that remotely worked was when I overwrote the ingress values as

```
nginx-ingress:
  controller:
    publishService:
      enabled: true
    service:
      type: NodePort
      nodePorts:
        https: "40000"
```

This does enable https, but it picks up kubernetes' fake certs, rather than my cert from the container

Edit 2:
For some reason, the ssl-passthrough is not working. I enforced it as

```
nginx-ingress:
  controller:
    extraArgs:
      enable-ssl-passthrough: ""
```

when I describe the deployment, I can see it in the args but when I check with `kubectl ingress-nginx backends` as described in https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/kubectl-plugin/#backends, it says "sslPassThrough:false"

Comment: have you  tried to expose service as NodePort?

Comment: Yes, sorry I missed that. Modified the question!

Answer (score 1):

SSL Passthrough requires a specific flag to be passed to the nginx controller while starting since it is disabled by default.

> SSL Passthrough is **disabled by default** and requires starting the controller with the [`--enable-ssl-passthrough`](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/cli-arguments/) flag.

Since `ssl-passthrough` works on layer 4 of the OSI model and not on the layer 7 (HTTP) using it will invalidate all the other annotations that you set on the ingress object.

So at your deployment level you have specify this flag under `args`:

```
containers:
        - name: controller
          image: us.gcr.io/k8s-artifacts-prod/ingress-nginx/controller:v0.34.1@sha256:0e072dddd1f7f8fc8909a2ca6f65e76c5f0d2fcfb8be47935ae3457e8bbceb20
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          lifecycle:
            preStop:
              exec:
                command:
                  - /wait-shutdown
          args:
            - /nginx-ingress-controller
            - --enable-ssl-passthrough
```

Comment: I tried that but for some reason the ingress isn't picking it up. One way to check was by ```kubectl ingress-nginx backends --deployment my-ingress```, according to https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/kubectl-plugin/#backends, it still says "sslPassthrough: false",  although it shows up in the args section of ingress deployment

Answer (score 1):

There are several thingns you need to setup if you want to use ssl-passthrough.

1. First is to set proper host name:

   ```
   spec:
     rules:
     - host: example.com    <- HERE
       http:
         ...
   ```

   It's mentioned [in documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/#ssl-passthrough):

   > SSL Passthrough leverages SNI [Server Name Indication] and reads the virtual domain from the
   > TLS negotiation, which requires compatible clients. After a connection
   > has been accepted by the TLS listener, it is handled by the controller
   > itself and piped back and forth between the backend and the client.
   >
   > If there is no hostname matching the requested host name, the request
   > is handed over to NGINX on the configured passthrough proxy port
   > (default: 442), which proxies the request to the default backend.

---

2. Second thing is setting `--enable-ssl-passthrough` flag as already mentioned in separate answer by @thomas.

   Just edit the nginx ingress deployment and add this line to args list:

   ```
    - --enable-ssl-passthrough
   ```

---

3. Third thing that has to be done is use to use the following annotations in your ingress object definition:

   ```
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
   ```

IMPORTANT: [In docs](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#ssl-passthrough) you can read:

> Attention
>
> Because SSL Passthrough works on layer 4 of the OSI model (TCP) and
> not on the layer 7 (HTTP), using SSL Passthrough invalidates all the
> other annotations set on an Ingress object.

This means that all other annotations are useless from now on. This applies to annotations like `force-ssl-redirect`, `affinity` and also to paths you defined (e.g. `path: /myserver`). Since traffic is end-to-end encrypted, all ingress sees is some gibberish and all it can do is pass this data to the application based on dns name (SNI).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is an open issue
https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/5686

So, I had to revert back to using my certs as default certificates and mounting it as tls sercets.

Comment: What do you mean by "revert back to using my certs as default certificates"?
Could you please share your current code as I am facing the same problem. thx